# Python Thread that cannot be called again

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I am trying to implement an alarm trigger functionality for an IoT device using Python thread, but have a problem understanding the logic for it.

**My scenario:**

I have a sensor that can send me triggers for motion and tamper. So if there is any motion or tamper detected by the sensor, it should trigger the siren.

The Siren is on a GPIO port that I have configured in a separate class. There is only one siren.

**Now my code:**

```
def siren(self):
    print("Turning on the siren")
    setGPIOvalue(<port>, <value>)


def triggeralarms(self,):       
    siren_trigger = threading.Thread(target=self.siren)

    if (alarmed == True):                    
    # Check for all the sensors if there is any alarms to be triggered
    for i in range(len(a.senList)):
            # Motion alarm
            if (motion == True):
                print("-----------------> Setting the motion alarm")                        
                if not siren_trigger.is_alive():
                    siren_trigger.start()
                    motion == False


            # Tamper alarm    
            if (tamper == True):
                print("-----------------> Setting the tamper alarm")
                if not siren_trigger.is_alive():
                    siren_trigger.start()
                    tamper == False
```

In the siren, there is a delay of 10 sec.

The triggeralarms() function keeps on checking the status in loop.

**Issue:**

Now the problem is that the code triggers the GPIO for both motion and tamper sometimes. So both motion and tamper create a thread to trigger the siren.

What I am looking is for to somehow to check if the siren thread is already running, then it should now be started again.

For example, if the motion sensor triggers the siren, and I also receive the trigger for tamper, then if the siren thread is already running, tamper should not start the siren thread again.

I tried to by checking `siren_trigger.is_alive()` but it seems to be not working. 
I am missing the logic here.

Comment: A `thread` is not a _thread_. That is to say, a Python `thread` instance in your program is not the same thing as a thread object in the operating system (OS). The Python `thread` is merely your handle on an OS thread that gets created when you call `t.start()`, and which is _destroyed_ by the OS when the thread function reaches its end.  The designers of the Python threading library chose to remind you that each OS thread is a distinct object by forcing you to create a new Python `thread` each time you want a new OS thread.

Comment: Um, BTW, Why are you creating a new thread that does nothing but set a GPIO pin and then die?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I the setGPIOvalue() is a function that actually runs for 10sec that sets the GPIO pin high and then again make it low. But my idea was that if in the time being I get another alarm trigger from the sensor, then by putting the siren on a thread will help me to do both - run GPIO and also handle triggers from the sensor.

Comment: I'd do it differently: I'd have the `triggeralarms` function turn the siren on, and then start a `Timer(...)` that will turn it off after the ten seconds.  Then, for re-triggers,... um,... ah,... I don't have time to think about that right now, but I'd probably devise some means to cancel one timer and start another.